# Can't get app to update based on accelerometer data in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, accelerometer, android-sensors

I am trying to clear the text labels/output when the phone is shaken by using accelerometer data.

This is what I have:

```
imports ....
public class Main_Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener, SensorEventListener{

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1){

    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){

        double ax = event.values[0];
        double ay = event.values[1];
        double az = event.values[2];
        double a = Math.sqrt(ax*ax + ay*ay + az*az);

        if(a > 20){
            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.pBox)).setText("");
            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.aBox)).setText("");
            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.iBox)).setText("");
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.output)).setText("");
        }


    public void buttonClicked(View v){
        // getting values entered by user and showing output
    }
}
```

Everything works except when I shake my phone, the text doesn't clear.

Comment: Put a log statement before if condition displaying a value ... I think it might be less than 20 always

Comment: @PraveenSP I tried lower values but it doesn't work either.

Comment: What value it displaying for double variable a...?

Comment: Look this use this logic to detect shake....https://stackoverflow.com/a/5271532/9365212

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please create these as global var

```
private float acelVal,acelLast,shake;
```

Please use this login to get shake events in your `onSensorChanged()`

```
float x =event.values[0];
float y =event.values[1];
float z =event.values[2];
acelLast=acelVal;
acelVal=(float) Math.sqrt((double) (x*x)+(y*y)+(z*z));
float delta= acelVal-acelLast;
shake =shake*0.9f+delta;


if(shake>20){
    ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.pBox)).setText("");
    ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.aBox)).setText("");
    ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.iBox)).setText("");
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.output)).setText("");
}
```

This is the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5271532/7948109)

Hope this will help!